# Узнать где находится прототип JavaScript объекта

Tags: javascript, объекты

У меня есть некоторая страница со скриптом, скрипты подгружаются и создается некий объект с именем `VideoBalancer`

```
var video_balancer_options = {
  video_token: '3fc80821640c92a7',
  serial_token: '05637d0c8b3e7e2f23caaa4ab6ce0ee2',
  serial_group: 'serial_kp_661247',
  trailer_token: '13ef6d8166200d1d',
  content_type: 'Serial',
  partner_id: 4787,
  domain_id: 645774,
  host: 'mastarti.com',
  port: 80,
  proto: 'http://',
  ref: 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJyZWZfaG9zdCI6Im9ubGluZS1saWZlLnh5eiIsInJlcV9ob3N0IjoibW9vbndhbGsuY2MiLCJleHAiOjE1NjUxODQzMjMsInRva2VuIjoiMDU2MzdkMGM4YjNlN2UyZjIzY2FhYTRhYjZjZTBlZTIifQ.PDXjG_lHa6okRIwaXjbX4OUekNbpVGZW5OUy4I5Q4uE',
  ref_url: "http%3A%2F%2Fmastarti.com%2Fserial%2F05637d0c8b3e7e2f23caaa4ab6ce0ee2%2Fiframe%3Fref%3DeyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJyZWZfaG9zdCI6Im9ubGluZS1saWZlLnh5eiIsInJlcV9ob3N0IjoibW9vbndhbGsuY2MiLCJleHAiOjE1NjUxODQzMjMsInRva2VuIjoiMDU2MzdkMGM4YjNlN2UyZjIzY2FhYTRhYjZjZTBlZTIifQ.PDXjG_lHa6okRIwaXjbX4OUekNbpVGZW5OUy4I5Q4uE",
  ref_back: "",
  thumbnails: {
    visible: false,
    count: 0,
    pattern: 'null',
  },
  user_country: 'RU',
  adv: {"reserve_vast":{"urls":["//z.cdn.braun634.com/load?o=v\u0026z=1528370177\u0026r=1\u0026random=5556581106","//z.cdn.braun634.com/load?o=v\u0026z=1389907986\u0026r=1\u0026random=2260704060","//n1307adserv.xyz/zOj0OTEaVHiRy0-KO2Bu1458xJI0aK3XnWwOr5NNAfdGNTmD5NwbE7HkX6vWNJTmbG4BZFX7eY701R_dELVtqHshLA98_jMM"]},"adb_vast":{"urls":[{"name":"int_adm_ru_1_adblock","src":"https://5edeb195868e2195.com/QoU72XtOvA34uytUM5z6SQVWytS7rSMyUzozquZUQsAtaMmAZ6ovqtt"}],"timers":[5]},"vast":{"urls":[{"name":"int_adm_ru_1","src":"https://ed98512111bb19e5.in.net/39p4U2QAysm5qUyAaSX7vrtVvS7o42X5vt4a5yyZU3445SQoU5yUW"}],"timers":[15]},"chain":"base.special_vast_15_nil.vast_1_adm_ru_15"},
  c_path: 'prebid-',
  r_path: 'nomaig.com',
  r_path_ua: 'kosuperc.com',
  device: {"mobile":false,"android":false,"ios":false,"desktop":true,"browser":"generic browser","platform_major_version":0.0},
  lang: 'ru',
  assets_host: 'http://185.38.12.41',
  player_skin: 'moonwalk',
  p2p: true,
  start_time: null,
  continue_time: null,
  subtitles: null,
  translations: [["05637d0c8b3e7e2f23caaa4ab6ce0ee2","AniDUB"]],
  movie_translations: null,
  seasons: [1],
  episodes: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
  season: 1,
  episode: 12,
  nocontrols: false,
  nocontrols_seasons: false,
  nocontrols_translations: false,
  nocontrols_episodes: false,
  nocontrols_trailer: false,
  nocontrols_full_video: false,
  poster_url: null,
  autoplay: false,
  autoswitch: true,
  next_episode_button: false,
  track_watching: true,
  env: 'production'
};

$(function() {
  window.video_balancer = new VideoBalancer(video_balancer_options);
});
```

Как я могу посмотреть где этот прототип, или узнать откуда создается этот объект при помощи браузера?

Мне нужно этот объект перенести на другой язык, поэтому необходимо узнать где его прототип.

Comment: эммм, поставить точку остановки на строке с конструктором, далее в консоли `console.log(VideoBalancer)`, вам выведется текст, кликаете, вас перенесет в нужный файл

Comment: скорее всего у вас `VideoBalancer` глобальный, так что можно сразу выводить в консоль, без точек остановки

Comment: Да, это помогло! Удалось найти и определения функций, и всего остального. Запишите ответом, уточнение, помогла печать объекта в конлось.

Comment: сделал как ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  window.video_balancer = new VideoBalancer(video_balancer_options);
});
```

Такая запись говорит о том, что `VideoBalancer` скорее всего доступен глобально. Значит, для того, что бы найти где находится определение этого класса, достаточно:

1 - Открыть консоль разработчика (F12) 
2 - Вписать в консоль `console.log(VideoBalancer)`, а можно сразу `VideoBalancer` 
3 - Кликнуть на ответ, который выдаст консоль.

Тут вас должно перебросить во вкладку `resources` и открыться нужный файл с местом определения